# StringGrid Delphi - "carrossel"

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte com minha StringGrid, tenho um cadastro de 100 produtos, e gostaria que ela mostrasse 10 produtos por vez, em uma espécie de loop infinito. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Controle de `fetch` nunca é feito num grid, independente do mesmo ser *dataware* ou não.
O controle deve ser feito no `dataset`. Presumo que você deva estar usando o *FireDAC*, assim sendo em `FecthOptions`, sete a propriedade `Mode` para `fmOnDemand` e a propriedade `RowsetSize` para **10**.
Outra coisa, no evento `AfterGetRecords` do `DataSet`, talvez seja necessário aumentar o `RowCount` do `StringGrid`.
Dependendo de como você está alimentando os dados no `StringGrid`, pode ser necessário alguma configuração a mais.
Se ficar com dúvidas, poste aí.

Comment: estou usando Firemonkey, não sei se isso interfere em algo

Comment: Nesse caso não interfere em nada. Você está usando o `LiveBindings`?

Answer (score -1):

não, só firemonkey mesmo, eu quero fazer algo assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link da imagem: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3RZV5-YfKWo/maxresdefault.jpg

ai ele vai alternando os produtos, consegui montar a tela, trazer os produtos certinho, porem não consigo fazer esse alternação de 2 em 2 , 5 em 5.